# Matlab, if condition without loop

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements

There are matices A(n,1), B(n,1) and the following condition inside a loop

```
for i=1:m
   if ( A(i, 1) > error )
      B(i,1) = 0;
   else
      B(i,1) = exp (-A(i,1) / 100)
   end
end
```

How to rewrite this condition without using any loop? Is it possible something like that

```
 if ( A(:, 1) > error )
      B(:,1) = 0;
   else
      B(:,1) = exp (-A(:,1) / 100)
 end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
idxs = (A > error);
B( idxs) = 0;
B(~idxs) = exp(-A(~idxs) / 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close with your suggestion.  The key is to form a "logical index."

```
i = A(:,1) > error;

B(i,:) = 0;
B(~i,:) = exp (-A(:,1) / 100);
```

Since your matrices A and B are vectors (one-dimensional matrices), the `(:,1)` and `(i,:)` aren't necessary in this case but as they were in your initial formulation, I left them in.  If you were using multi-dimensional matrices instead (m * n) you could form an (m * n) logical index rather than (m * 1) by doing `i = A > error;` instead of `i = A(:,1) > error;`